# How to draw a 3D circle that is tangent to two lines?

Tags: geometry, circles, 3d

I have two 3D space lines on the same plane (M-R and N-R), and I have two known point on the individual line (M and N). the angle between two lines is unknown. And now I want to draw a circle that is tangent to both of the lines (on the same plane), and touch two known points. I know the center (o) is where two perpendicular of lines in M and N intersect each other. but I do not know how to calculate perpendicular line in 3D space and in specified plane.

[image]

Or something like this image:

[image]

Comment: A circle is inherently 2D, a 3D circle doesn't exist. As I've mentioned on your SO question already, everything is within the same plane. Rotate your system such that you've only got in-plane coordinates, then solve for the circle's centre (this is easy) and then rotate back to 3D. From basic geometry you know the angle O-M to M-R to be 90 deg, same for O-N to N-R. Find out where the two perpendicular lines cross, that's the centre. Distance from the centre to either M or N (those are equal) give you the circle's radius.

Comment: You can also note that the center lies on the angle bisector of the two lines.

Comment: @insipidintegrator thanks for your comment.. is it general?

Comment: Yes it is general. Prove the congruence of the two right triangles and see it for yourself!

Comment: If you know only two points $M$ and $N$ you cannot recover circle as unique. Do you have $R$ also?

Answer (score 1):

First find the coordinates of the center $O$  and the radius $r$. By symmetry $O$ is on the line through $B$ and $\frac{A+C}{2}$. Call $\vec{w} = \frac{A+C}{2}-B$. So $O = B + t\vec{w}$ for some $t$. We can solve this $t$-value from the condition

$$\vec{BC} \perp \vec{CO}.$$

Then take the orthonormal basis for the plane consisting of $v_1 = \frac{\vec{OC}}{|\vec{OC}|}$ and $v_2 = \frac{\vec{CB}}{|\vec{CB}|}$. Now the circle is parametrized by

$$\gamma(t) = O + r\cos(t) v_1 + r\sin(t) v_2.$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we know $M,N,R$ with $\|M-R\| = \|N-R\|$ we have

$$
(M-R)\cdot(N-R) = \|M-R\|^2\cos\alpha,\ \ \|O-R\|\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) = \|M-R\|,\ \  r = \|M-O\| = \|M-R\|\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)
$$

and also

$$
O-R = \frac{(M+N)/2-R}{\|(M+N)/2-R\|}\frac{\|M-R\|}{\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}
$$

now making $\hat n = \frac{(M-R)\times(N-R)}{\|(M-R)\times(N-R)\|}$ we can define the circle

$$
p = O + r\left(\hat u\cos\theta+\hat v\sin\theta\right)
$$

with $\|\hat u\|=\|\hat v\|=1,\ \ \hat u\cdot\hat v=\hat u\cdot\hat n=\hat v\cdot\hat n=0$